# How can i calculate recurrence formula including minimization with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate recurrence formula whose detail is below including minimization with numpy. Also, I don't want to use numpy's reference if I could because of calculation time.

Here is recurrence formula I want to calculate: `(DTW)` `(*)`

```
g[i,j] = d[i,j] + min(g[i-1,j],g[i-1,j-1],g[i-1,j-2])
```

I tried to calculate (*) with "for loop", then the calculation time is about 2 min! in spite of g.shape = (2000, 2000)...
The code is like below:

```
indexes = [[-1,0],[-1,-1],[-1,-2]] # for genelize

for i in range(1, g_rows):
    for j in range(g_cols):
        tmp = np.zeros(len(indexes))
        for k in range(len(indexes)):
            i_ = i + indexes[k][0]
            j_ = j + indexes[k][1]
            if i_ >= 0 and i_ < g_rows and j_ >= 0 and j_ < g_cols:
                tmp[k] = d[i,j] + g[i_,j_]
            else:
                tmp[k] = np.nan 

        g[i,j] = np.nanmin(tmp)

        for ~ # back tracking for DTW
```

Therefore, I'd like to do faster than above code. I think this code is too redundant...

If it's a simple recurrence formula:

```
a[i,j] = u[i+1,j] - u[i,j] + u[i,j+1] - u[i,j]
```

And then using slice `(a)`:

```
a =  u[1:,0:-1] - u[0:-1,0:-1] + u[0:-1,1:] -u[0:-1,0:-1]
```

I'd like to calculate `(*)` like `(a)`.
Are there any solutions?

Comment: Use some for loops

Comment: Hi jkjk, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  I suspect that the reason you are getting down-voted is because you haven't shown your effort to solve this yourself prior to asking.  Generally speaking, part of a good SO question is an explanation of what you've tried so far that hasn't worked.  When you get a chance, could you edit your question a bit to clarify what you've tried so far?  Other than that, it looks fine to me!  Good luck :)

Comment: Except for something like `cumsum`, the fast numpy operations act on the whole array 'in-parallel'.  Technically they iterate in C code, but from the Python code perspective, `g[i,j]` is calculated at the same time as `g[i-1,j-2]`.  That doesn't fit well with something that must happen in a specific sequence.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Thank you for telling me who is beginner. You're right, I didn't show my effort, so I'll update this question for improving quality.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't know that. Thank you. How can (*) be calculated faster...
Is there other module except for numpy? or my code is too bad simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is intrinsically an iterative algorithm, so you probably can't do it all as a single vector op.  But, because each element in each column is computed independently, you could make this much faster by vectorizing your per-row computation:

```
g = np.zeros(d.shape) 
g[0, :] = d[0, :]
for i in range(1, d.shape[0]):
    g[i, 0] = d[i, 0] + g[i-1, 0]  # Edge condition for column 0
    g[i, 1] = d[i, 1] + np.minimum(g[i-1, 0], g[i-1, 1])  # Edge condition for column 1
    g[i, 2:] = d[i, 2:] + np.minimum.reduce([g[i-1,2:], g[i-1,1:-1], g[i-1,:-2]])  # Do remaining columns in single operation
```

I have not tested this code, but believe it should do what is needed.

Comment: Thank you for reply and showing code! I can calculate faster than before.

Comment: Surprisingly, calculation time using your code was less than 1 second! I studied slowness of using many "for loop". Thank you!